# git push single file to a remote tracking branch

Tags: git, github

Folks,

This is my use case: I have 3 branches, all three are remote tracking branches.

```
git branch
  release-alpha
* release-allUS
  master
```

Now I added a new file in release-allUS branch, I made a commit by doing this:

```
 git add filter_driver.rb 
 git commit -m "driver code"
```

Now I want to push only this file to the remote release-allUS branch, How do I do that? Thanks a lot for any feedback.

Answer (score 12):

Since all that you committed locally was that one file, a `git push` to your remote will work. Push will only push what has been committed locally.

```
git push origin release-allUS
```

As manojlds pointed out in the comments, this will only work if nothing else has been stages and there are no other unpushed local commits. If that is the case, you are are probably best creating a new tracking branch from the remote, cherry picking the local commit into the new branch, pushing to the remote, then rebasing the original tracking branch.

Answer (score 4):

i know you can push to a certain branch this way:

```
git push origin <branch>
```

I just took a quick look at the `git push --help` and it doesn't seem to say anything about sending a single file commit to a branch.

maybe one work around to this would be to have an `integration` branch that you never touch except when you want to push commits around.  if you're in your `integration` branch, you could do a `git cherry-pick <commit>` from your other branch bringing over only what was in that commit to the `integration` and then do a `git push origin integration`.